# Create FiniteDimensionalAlgebra from OperationTable

Tags: sage

Let's assume we have an [`OperationTable`](https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/matrices/sage/matrix/operation_table.html) -- `T`.

```
sage: T = OperationTable(Set, operation=operation, names='elements');
```

We would like to create a [`FiniteDimensionalAlgebra`](https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/algebras/sage/algebras/finite_dimensional_algebras/finite_dimensional_algebra.html) from `T`.

**Question.**
What is the fastest way to convert a table `T` to the form being expected by `FiniteDimensionalAlgebra`?

> The list table must have the following form: there exists a finite-dimensional k-algebra of degree n with basis (e1,…,en)
> (e1,… ,en) such that the i-th element of table is the matrix of right multiplication by ei with respect to the basis (e1,…,en).

**Example.**
An example of list of matrices accepted by `FiniteDimensionalAlgebra` over field `QQ`.

```py
sage: B = FiniteDimensionalAlgebra(QQ, [Matrix([[1,0,0], [0,1,0], [0,0,0]]), Matrix([[0,1,0], [0,0,0], [0,0,0]]), Matrix([[0,0,0], [0,0,0], [0,0,1]])])
```

---

An instance of `T`.

```
sage: T
```

```
.  a b c d e f g h i j
 +--------------------
a| a a a a a a a a a a
b| a a a a a a b b b b
c| a a a b b b b b c c
d| a a b b b c c c c d
e| a a b b c c c d d e
f| a a b c c c d e e e
g| a b b c c d e e f f
h| a b b c d e e f g g
i| a b c c d e f g g h
j| a b c d e e f g h i
```

```
sage: T.table()
```

```
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1],
 [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2],
 [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3],
 [0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4],
 [0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4],
 [0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5],
 [0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 6],
 [0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 6, 7],
 [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]]
```

Comment: How are you producing `T`? If you have a finite monoid (namely, the elements `a`, `b`, ..., `j`) called `M`, then you can do `M.algebra(QQ)` to get the corresponding algebra.

Comment: I have a custom operation `def operation(x,y)` and a custom, finite set `S`.
`operation(x,y)` is closed under `S`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I have managed left/right correctly here, but something like this will work:

```
# elt_to_idx: looks like {'a': 0, 'b': 1, ...}
elt_to_idx = {b:a for (a,b) in enumerate(T.column_keys())}

mat_list = []

# Convert T to a list of matrices.
for a in T.column_keys():
    # dictionary to define matrix for right multiplication by a:
    dict_a = {}
    for (idx_b, b) in enumerate(T.column_keys()):
        # Each row (or should it be column?) should have a single entry of "1"
        dict_a[idx_b, elt_to_idx[T[b, a]]] = 1
    mat_list.append(matrix(QQ, 4, 4, dict_a))

FiniteDimensionalAlgebra(QQ, mat_list)
```